# What group of colors would go well with these colors?

Tags: color, color-profile

[image]

I am trying to find a couple more colors (hex#s) that go well with these colors. I made a calendar to which people can add many different groups. I wanted to have about 4 more of these. I don't really understand how to find good colors that match. It's one of those things I've never really understood.

Comment: You might want to read into colour theory a bit. We have the [tag:color-theory] tag, and there's a series of great articles on it on Smashing Magazine, [this](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/01/28/color-theory-for-designers-part-1-the-meaning-of-color/) being the first. Good luck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Colors similar to these might work, assuming the colors are for team colors or something similar.

`\#8C8C8C \#EB2E32 \#A349A4 \#141414`

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It really depends on what you want to do with the colours. If you're plotting multiple plits in a single graph, you need way different colours thanfor a good colour scheme you'd make a poster design with.

Since Zach already provided good colours for the contrasting-graph scenario, I'll add my advice for creating a balanced colour scheme. Since the current colour scheme already includes four different hues, I'd shy away from adding any more. Try and add multiple levels of white and black to your existing colours, creating *tints* (mixtures with white), *tones* (mixtures with black) and *shades* (mixtures with grey) of your existing hues. You essentially change the Saturation and Brightness/Value numbers for your existing colours, while keeping their Hue value intact.

eg:

[image]

Colours with the same hue value, but different saturation and brightness (or value) always go well together.